# Prove $F'(x) = f(x,x) + \int_a^x{\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}dy}$

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ be a function from $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ and define $F(x)=\int_a^x{f(x,y)dy}$. Prove, or show, the following;

$$F'(x) = f(x,x) + \int_a^x{\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}dy}$$

What I tried to do, is as follows;
   $$\int_a^x{f(x,y)dy}=F(x,x)-F(x,a)$$
And next;
   $$\frac{dF(x)}{dx}=\frac{d F(x,x)}{dx}-\frac{dF(x,a)}{dx}$$
However, I'm not sure if that is legit, considering the dependency of the integral on $x$.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: $F(x)$ is a single variable ($x$) function!

Comment: Allright, but I have still no clue, even if I change the $\partial$ in a $d$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an imediate application of the theorem of differentiating under the integral sign (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign):
$$
F'(x)=f(x,x)(\frac{dx}{dx})-f(x,a)(\frac{da}{dx})+\int_{a}^{x}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}dy = f(x,x)+\int_{a}^{x}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}dy
$$

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add more specific continuity/differentiability requirements
to prove this formally, but this gives the idea behind it:

Write 
$F(x+h)-F(x)  = 
\int_x^{x+h} f(x+h,y) dy + \int_a^x (f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)) dy$.

Show that the first term is approximately $f(x,x)h$, and the second term
is approximately
$(\int_a^x{\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}dy})h$.